# How to count pronouns, nouns and verbs of sentences in rows of a csv file

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, nltk

I wanted to count how many pronouns, nouns and verbs exist in rows of a csv file. And save the count in the file itself with a new column. I am fairly new with NLTK

This my truncated clues.csv

```
id  STORY
0   Sitting for long?
1   In his talk titled, 'Is Sitting the New Smoking?'
2   Prolonged sitting is an independent risk factor, even if you exercise regularly.
```

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
import nltk
from nltk.tag import pos_tag
from nltk import word_tokenize
from collections import Counter

news = pd.read_csv("clues.csv")

news['token'] = news.apply(lambda row: nltk.word_tokenize(row['STORY']), axis=1)
news['pos_tags'] = news.apply(lambda row: nltk.pos_tag(row['token']), axis=1)

tag_count_df = pd.DataFrame(news['pos_tags'].map(lambda x: Counter(tag[1] for tag in x)).to_list())

news['count']=pd.concat([news, tag_count_df], axis=1).fillna(0).drop(['pos_tags', 'token'], axis=1)


news.to_csv("clues.csv")
```

I kept on getting ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 50, placement implies 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
df = pd.read_clipboard(sep='\s\s+')

df['token'] = df.apply(lambda row: nltk.word_tokenize(row['STORY']), axis=1)
df['pos_tags'] = df.apply(lambda row: nltk.pos_tag(row['token']), axis=1)

tag_count_df = pd.DataFrame(df['pos_tags'].map(lambda x: Counter(tag[1] for tag in x)).to_list())

pd.concat([df, tag_count_df], axis=1).fillna(0).drop(['pos_tags', 'token'], axis=1)
```

Out:

```
   id                                              STORY   ''    ,  .   CD  \
0   0                                  Sitting for long?  0.0  0.0  1  0.0   
1   1  In his talk titled, 'Is Sitting the New Smoking?'  1.0  1.0  1  1.0   
2   2  Prolonged sitting is an independent risk facto...  0.0  1.0  1  0.0   

    DT  IN   JJ   NN  NNP  PRP  PRP$   RB  VBG  VBN  VBP  VBZ  
0  0.0   1  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0  1.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  
1  1.0   1  0.0  1.0  2.0  0.0   1.0  0.0  1.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  
2  1.0   1  2.0  3.0  0.0  1.0   0.0  2.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  1.0
```

Comment: i tried to use your code using my csv file, but i couldn't get the count for the nouns, pronouns and verbs, the last 2 lines of codes gave me errors. I edited my codes above for you to see how i edited my codes with yours

Comment: @strawberrylatte The last line should be `news = pd.concat([news, tag_count_df], axis=1).fillna(0).drop(['pos_tags', 'token'], axis=1)` You were trying to put a dataframe into a column.

Comment: hello, i know this post is months old, but, can you explain to me, how your code also included punctuations? I was wondering if i could get the rest of the punctuations as well